# Computed property doesn't get updated on the frontend

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a component called `scanstart-participants-count` this component will show the total count of participants added to a specified scan & target audience. in my Handlebar i call the component with `{{scanstart-participants-count scan=scan targetAudience=targetAudience}}` and this works all correct, except when the `isValid` column in my `participant` model changes to `true` to frontend count stays on `0`. I just can't figure out what i am doing wrong

**Component: scanstart-participants-count.js**

import Ember from 'ember'

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName:           'div',
    classNames:        'participant',
    scan:              null,
    targetAudience:    null,

    scanParticipants:  Ember.computed('scan.id', 'targetAudience.scanParticipants.[]', function () {
        // Default properties
        const scanId           = this.get('scan.id')
        const scanParticipants = this.get('targetAudience.scanParticipants')

        console.log('scanParticipants count scan: '+scanParticipants.filterBy('scan.id', scanId).get('length')) // Correct output

        // Filter by scan ID.
        return scanParticipants.filterBy('scan.id', scanId)
    }),
    participants:      Ember.computed('scanParticipants.[]', function () {
        // Default properties
        const scanParticipants = this.get('scanParticipants')

        // Map by participant
        return scanParticipants.mapBy('participant')
    }),
    // TODO: Change "participants.content.@each.participantValid" to "participants.@each.participantValid" after update to 2.3.0
    participantsValid: Ember.computed('participants.content.@each.participantValid', function () {
        // Default properties
        const participants = this.get('participants')

        console.log('participants count: '+this.get('participants').get('length')) // Correct output
        console.log('participants valid count: '+this.get('participants').filterBy('participantValid', false).get('length')) // Correct out put when loads first time, nothing happens when the isValid column change's to true. (First time: participantsValid = true = 0, participantsValid = false = 3)

        // Filter by isValid = true.
        return participants.filterBy('participantValid', true)
    })
})
```

**Component handlebar**

```
{{targetAudience.title}}: <span class="{{if participantsValid.length '_muted' '_danger'}}">{{participantsValid.length}}</span>
```

**Model: target-audience.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data'

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title:                       DS.attr('string'),
    singular:                    DS.attr('string'),
    participantsMin:             DS.attr('number'),
    participantsMax:             DS.attr('number'),
    scanGroups:                  DS.hasMany('scanGroup', {async: true}),
    scanParticipants:            DS.hasMany('scanParticipant', {async: true}),
})
```

**Model: scan-participant.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data'

export default DS.Model.extend({
    hash:           DS.attr('string'),
    opened:         DS.attr('boolean'),
    finished:       DS.attr('boolean'),
    scan:           DS.belongsTo('scan',           {async: true}),
    results:        DS.hasMany('result',           {async: true}),
    participant:    DS.belongsTo('participant',    {async: true}),
    targetAudience: DS.belongsTo('targetAudience', {async: true})
})
```

**Model: participant.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data'

var inflector = Ember.Inflector.inflector
    inflector.irregular('participant', 'participant')

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name:             DS.attr('string'),
    email:            DS.attr('string'),
    participantValid: Ember.computed('name', 'email', function () {
        // Default vars
        let name  = this.get('name')
        let email = this.get('email')

        // Set validation status
        if((name !== '') && (email !== ''))
            return true;

        return false
    }),
    targetAudiences:  DS.hasMany('targetAudience', {async: true}),

    /**
     * Scans
     */
    scans:            DS.hasMany('scan',            {async: true}),
    scanParticipants: DS.hasMany('scanParticipant', {async: true}),
})
```

**Code updated what it is now 17-02-2016***

**version info**
Ember             : 2.1.0
Ember Data        : 2.1.0
jQuery            : 1.11.3
Ember Simple Auth : 1.0.0

Comment: Doesn't the dependency need to be `targetAudience.scanParticipants.@each.id`?

Comment: @torazaburo: Nope, it just needs to look at the array, if one is added and/or removed it has to be updated. but the problem is not there.
The problem is `participantsValid` method in my component i think, because the count doesn't get updated if an `isValid` column changes to `true` or to `false` but if i change the `true` to `false` in the component file it outputs the correct count.

Comment: isValid should be a computed property of name and email, no need for an observer.

Comment: @Gaurav: IF i make it a computed property, the property doesn't get updated when i am changing the input's on the fly trough `input` elements... thats why i build an observer in the model.

Comment: What input elements? It should change automatically, so long as isValid is bound to something.

Comment: I have a feeling that your `isValid: attr('boolean')` is conflicting with the `DS.Model` internal `isValid` flag (both of which would be accessed via `model.get('isValid')`)... can you try renaming the model attribute to something else?  also i agree... prefer computed properties over observers.

Comment: @Gaurav: thats correct Ember Data is getting updated, but the 'isValid' value doesn't when it is updated.

Comment: @Grapho: I think your right if i do it the way like Gaurav explains, but as i am using Ember 2.1.0 il take a look at the answer beneath. Thank you for pointing me out!

Comment: @Gaurav and Grapho: I have restarted ember serve and now the way Gaurav told me is work good with the property name `isValid` :). Thanks for the tip ! now i have to fix the bug of the count on the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending around with the code and the solutions of @Lux, @Grapho & @Gaurav.

It is finally working after spending more then a week to this bug, where the real problem relies i can't figure out, because after it worked i changed it back to the old code as much as possible and it stay's working, below the working code:

**Component: scanstart-participants-count.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember'

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName:           'div',
    classNames:        'participant',
    scan:              null,
    targetAudience:    null,

    scanParticipants:  Ember.computed('scan.id', 'targetAudience.scanParticipants.[]', function () {
        // Default properties
        const scanId           = this.get('scan.id')
        const scanParticipants = this.get('targetAudience.scanParticipants')

        // Filter by scan ID.
        return scanParticipants.filterBy('scan.id', scanId)
    }),
    participants:      Ember.computed('scanParticipants.[]', function () {
        // Default properties
        const scanParticipants = this.get('scanParticipants')

        // Map by participant
        return scanParticipants.mapBy('participant')
    }),
    participantsValid: Ember.computed('participants.@each.isValid', function () {
        // Default properties
        const participants = this.get('participants')

        // Filter by isValid = true.
        return participants.filterBy('isValid', true)
    })
})
```

**Model: participant.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data'

var inflector = Ember.Inflector.inflector
    inflector.irregular('participant', 'participant')

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name:    DS.attr('string'),
    email:   DS.attr('string'),

    targetAudiences:  DS.hasMany('targetAudience', {async: true}),

    isValid: Ember.computed('name', 'email', function () {
        // Default vars
        let name  = this.get('name')
        let email = this.get('email')

        // Set validation status
        if((name !== '') && (email !== ''))
            return true;

        return false
    }),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe [this bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12475) causes your issue.
`participants` is an PromiseArray (because of the async relationship) and `@each` is there broken at the moment.

Replace this

```
participantsValid: Ember.computed('participants.@each.isValid', function () {
```

with

```
participantsValid: Ember.computed('participants.content.@each.isValid', function () {
```

as a temporary bugfix.

Comment: i disagree. this is not a bug. the issue that you linked to is marked closed.. and personally i have not seen `@each` fail for me as of yet.

Comment: Its closed on 2.3, not 2.1 or 2.2. We don't know the Ember version pcdsopacua is using, and this would be a simple reason for this behavior!

Comment: Thats right, i am using 2.1. Im sorry for not putting the versions in the main topic! I am going to test this right away @Lux

Comment: @Lux: I have tried it with `participants.content.@each.isValid` i have also tried Grapho his solution about the property name and changed it to `participantsValid` but both situations doesnt fix my problem, i have also merged both situations to make sure i dont use `isValid` property.

Comment: It was not the content bug, afterall! i am posting the code below that is working but i cant explain why it is working now, to me it still looks the same as i started the topic except i have added @Gaurav his solution (comment on main post) in the model for the valid state.